# How to get data snapshot from FireStore with AngularFire? (Not set a listener to receive data-change events.)

Tags: angular, google-cloud-firestore, angularfire2

The Cloud Firestore [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data) says that there are two ways to retrieve data:

- Call a method to get the data.
- Set a listener to receive data-change events.

The AngularFire documentation shows the latter, how to make an `Observable` and use `valueChanges()` to listen for data-change events. That works great.

I don't see any AngularFire documentation for `get()` to retrieve a data snapshot. I tried this

```js
constructor(
    public firestore: AngularFirestore,
) { }

onGetDocument() {
    this.firestore.collection('greatest-computer-scientists').doc('Ada Lovelace').get()
      .then((doc: any) => {
        if (doc.exists) {
          console.log("Document data:", doc.data());
        } else {
          console.log("No such document!");
        }
      }).catch((error: any) => {
        console.log("Error getting document:", error);
      });
}
```

The error message is:

```
TS2339: Property 'then' does not exist on type 'Observable<DocumentSnapshot<unknown>>'.

87       .then((doc: any) => {
          ~~~~
```

That makes sense. Promises don't come from Observables. But when did I make an Observable?

Let's change from modular (Web version 9) to namespaced (Web version 8):

```js
constructor(
    public firestore: AngularFirestore,
) { }

onGetDocument() {
    this.docRef = this.firestore.collection('greatest-computer-scientists').doc('Ada Lovelace');
    this.docSnap = getDoc(this.docRef);
    if (this.docSnap.exists()) {
      console.log("Document data:", this.docSnap.data());
    } else {
      // doc.data() will be undefined in this case
      console.log("No such document!");
    }
}
```

The error is

```
FirebaseError: Expected type 'Zu', but it was: a custom AngularFirestoreDocument object
```

This suggests that we're getting the data from the database but TypeScript is throwing an error because I didn't set the type. Let's set `docSnap` as an array of strings:

```js
docSnap: string[] | null = null;
```

Now the error message gets interesting:

```
TS2740: Type 'Promise<DocumentSnapshot<unknown>>' is missing the following properties from type 'string[]': length, pop, push, concat, and 28 more.
```

We're getting a Promise back, not an Observable. And we might be getting data back. How do I get a data snapshot to Angular from Cloud FireStore?

Answer (score 0):

The `get()` method in `AngularFirestore` returns an `Observable` that will only ever fire a single event. If I read the code correctly, it happens [here](https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/rxfire/blob/750debd983f4cdc68d05ac5e1c631ef808c8a3e1/firestore/lite/fromRef.ts#L5-L12) in RxFire - but I'm not entirely sure of that.

If you want to deal with a promise, you can call `first()` on the observable.

Comment: I suspect that AngularFire never implemented `get()`. I can get data using `valueChanges()` so maybe I don't need `get()`? I've used `get()` a million times, I'm used to this method.

Comment: The `get()` in the JavaScript SDK (which you can use if you want) doesn't return an observable, which is what RxFire wants to do. So AFAIK it returns you an observable with a single event. Calling `first()` on that observable then gives you a promise of that first event. Did you try calling `first()` yet? Did it work? Was there an error?